# Reload page after click on <a> to get new data from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, reload, multilingual

I'm writing a multilingual web and the logic is next:

1. By default there is a "lang.tmp" file with default data "eng".
2. When index.php loads it takes data from "lang.tmp" and sets the default language loading data from lang.php:

   ```
   include("lang/".file_get_contents("lang.tmp").".php");
   ```
3. If user wants to change language, he clicks on link created with php, which rewrites data in "lang.tmp":

   ```
   include("lang/languages.php");
   $i=0;
   while (list($key, $value) = each($languages))
   {
       echo '<li class="lang"><a href="index.php?'.$key.'"><div id="langBox">'.$value.'</div></a></li>';
       if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == $key)
       {
           $fp=fopen("lang.tmp","w");
           fwrite($fp,basename($key));
            fclose($fp);
       }
   ```

   SO! The problem is: after rewriting the "lang.tmp" file I need to reload the page with the same "index.php" address to get new type of language.
4. I've tried

   ```
   header("Location: index.php");
   ```

and obviously it doesn't work because URL is the same, so I'm getting error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.
```

2. I also tried JavaScript:

   ```
   $("div #langMenu").click(function() {
           location.reload();
           console.log ("Clicked!");
   });
   ```

But it doesn't worked either. Page reloads with new language only after **second click** on a link, but that's not what everybody needs ))

Would you be so kind to link where I'm wrong or what are the other options to reload page in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `header` redirect *should* work, that error means text has
   already been shown (you can only make that call when the page is
   loading, not once you've sent content).
2. The logic is flawed in that a single user will change the language
   for the entire site.
3. Why not just make the `<a>` a link to the page in the first place?

Comment: 1. I understand what "header" is doing, but how can I use it if page is already loaded (to avoid that error) and is it links to the same index.php.
2. Thanks, I understand that logic looks bad this way. In final version I plan to use cookies for this "lang.tmp" info, not a one file for all on a server ))

Comment: What about #3? (Would like an answer before I elaborate on #1).

Comment: The overall idea is to make web dynamic. If I use `index.php&lang` it is, but if I start using `index1.php, index2.php, etc` I'm loosing whole idea.
If that was the question? :)

Comment: You can make links to the current page you know... Especially with PHP.

Comment: Yes, to link to the same page I use `header` but thats where I'm getting error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.` because this page was already loaded from the server.

Comment: OK! I've solved it. Thanks for your input ))

I made redirection. 
If new language clicked it redirects user to "lang.php" :
` echo '<li class="lang"><a href="lang.php?'.$key.'"><div id="langBox">'.$value.'</div></a></li>';`

And there "index.php" with NEW lang chosen (server gives you new page and "header" works)
`<?php
include("lang/languages.php");
while (list($key, $value) = each($languages))
{
    if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == $key)
    {
        $fp=fopen("lang.tmp","w");
        fwrite($fp,basename($key));
        fclose($fp);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$("div #langBox").on('click',function() { 
     location.reload('true'); //Or window.location.href = window.location.href
     console.log ("Clicked!"); 
});
```

Comment: It really reloads the page, I can check it with FireBug. 
But it gives me a new language attributes only after SECOND click on a link <a>. And that is what I really don't get WHY? ))

Comment: @user2498129 It's probably caching it.

Comment: I guess it is. I have to figure out how to make it with pure PHP first. Maybe to redirect to another page, which will redirect back to index.php with new data from lang.tmp. 
Anyway, thanks for your input.